# Maximum height of the staircase

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search

Given an integer A representing the square blocks. The height of each square block is 1. The task is to create a staircase of max height using these blocks. The first stair would require only one block, the second stair would require two blocks and so on. Find and return the maximum height of the staircase.

---

> Your submission failed for the following input: A : 92761
>
> Your function returned the following : 65536
> The expected returned value : 430

```
Approach:
We are interested in the number of steps and we know that each step Si uses exactly Bi number of bricks. We can represent this problem as an equation:
n * (n + 1) / 2 = T (For Natural number series starting from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 …)
n * (n + 1) = 2 * T
n-1 will represent our final solution because our series in problem starts from 2, 3, 4, 5…

Now, we just have to solve this equation and for that we can exploit binary search to find the solution to this equation. Lower and Higher bounds of binary search are 1 and T.
```

> CODE

```
public int solve(int A) {
        int l=1,h=A,T=2*A;
        while(l<=h)
        {
            int mid=l+(h-l)/2;
            if((mid*(mid+1))==T)  
                return mid;
            if((mid*(mid+1))>T && (mid!=0 && (mid*(mid-1))<=T) )
                return mid-1;
            if((mid*(mid+1))>T)
                h=mid-1;
            else
                l=mid+1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is that when you start with 92761 than mid*(mid+1) will be bigger than the maximum possible integer and become a negative value. Change to long instead of int.

Comment: In a staircase, A = h(h+1)/2, so h^2 + h =2A.  Solving gives h = (sqrt(8A+1)-1)/2.  No loops required.

Comment: @MattTimmermans You should post that as an answer.

Comment: If you want to solve this with binary search, you can speed things up by starting with your lower bound equal to `sqrt(A)`. But a better solution is the one proposed by Matt Timmermans in his comment. I added some detail in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using all these formulas? A simple `while()` loop should do the trick, eventually, it's just a simple Gaussian Sum ..

```
public static int calculateStairs(int blocks) {
    int lastHeight = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int currentHeight = 0; //number of bricks / level
    while (sum <= blocks) {
        lastHeight = currentHeight;
        currentHeight++;
        sum += currentHeight;
    }
    return lastHeight;
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing all that iterating when you can solve the problem by applying some simple math? And whereas your simple `while` loop is easier to code, a binary search will be much faster.

Comment: By the way, why the `Math.min` at the end? `lastHeight` will always be less than or equal to `currentHeight`. You can restructure your code to eliminate `lastHeight`, and eliminate one iteration of the loop in the process.

Comment: That's right :( My mistake. I've provided a solution, there are plenty. But of course, your approach is much more easier, thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the comment by Matt Timmermans:

You know that for `n` steps, you need `(n * (n + 1))/2` blocks. You want know, if given `B` blocks, how many steps you can create.

So you have:

```
(n * (n + 1))/2 = B
(n^2 + n)/2 = B
n^2 + n = 2B
n^2 + n - 2B = 0
```

That looks suspiciously like something for which you'd use the [quadratic formula](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/quadform.htm).

In this case, `a=1`, `b=1`, and `c=(-2B)`. Plugging the numbers into the formula:

```
n = ((-b) + sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a)
  = (-1 + sqrt(1 - 4*1*(-2B)))/(2*a)
  = (-1 + sqrt(1 + 8B))/2
  = (sqrt(1 + 8B) - 1)/2
```

So if you have 5050 blocks, you get:

```
n = (sqrt(1 + 40400) - 1)/2
  = (sqrt(40401) - 1)/2
  = (201 - 1)/2
  = 100
```

Try it with the [quadratic formula calculator](https://www.calculator.net/quadratic-formula-calculator.html). Use 1 for the value of a and b, and replace c with negative two times the number of blocks you're given. So in the example above, c would be -10100.

In your program, since you can't have a partial step, you'd want to truncate the result.

Answer (score -1):

So this should do the job as it also returns the expected value. Correct me if im wrong.

```
public int solve(int blocks) {
    int current; //Create Variables
    for (int x = 0; x < Integer.MAX_VALUE; x++) { //Increment until return
      current = 0; //Set current to 0

        //Implementation of the Gauss sum
        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) { //Sum up [1,*current height*]
            current += i;
        } //Now we have the amount of blocks required for the current height

        //Now we check if the amount of blocks is bigger than
        // the wanted amount, and if so we return the last one
        if (current > blocks) {
            return x - 1;
        }
    }
    return current;
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of iterating from 0 ? It's not the best solution, but yes, it returns the expected value. And the `last` variable isn't even used.

Comment: your right ill correct it. I forgot the remove it, after i replaced it witch x - 1. Also iterating from 0 was a dumb thing to since its one useless iterating. I just used the code generation for "fori" and left it like that